# Not able to display the contents of a list in a dictionary in form of a table in the razor view from controller

Tags: c#

I am very new to asp.net and c#.Actually, this may be a very simple question.But I am not able to display even after trying so many times.So, if anyone can tell me the answer it will be very helpful for my project.

My controller class:

```
public class ShowDoctorSpecialityListController : Controller

{
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AddService addService = new AddService();
            Dictionary<string,List<string>>SpecialityDoctorMap=
            addService.GetDoctorSpecialityList(); 
            ViewBag.SpecialityDoctorMap = SpecialityDoctorMap;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

The addService is my service class. It is returning the speciality names as key and the list of doctors for that particular speciality in the value part.The specialityDoctorMap has the speciality name in the key part and the list of doctors for that particular speciality name in the value part. I have checked using a debugger in my service class that the doctor list has been properly mapped for the particular speciality name.But I am not able to display the speciality name and the doctor name list particular to that speciality in form of table in my razor view page.

My cshtml code:-

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" >
            <tr>
                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.SpecialityDoctorMap)
                     {
                        <tr>
                         <td>@item.Key</td>
                          for(int x = 0; x < item.Value.Count; x++)
                          {
                           <td>@item.Value[x]</td>
                          }
                          </tr>
                     }
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Service class:-

//To get the Speciality Id and the corresponding Speciality Name

```
    public Dictionary<Int32, string> GetSpecialityList()
    {
        conn.GetConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.GetCommand(Queries.GetSpeciality);
        List<Int32> list = new List<Int32>();
        Dictionary<Int32, string> SpecialityIdNameMap = new Dictionary<Int32, string>();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = null;
        mySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            SpecialityInfo specialityInfo = new SpecialityInfo();
            specialityInfo.specialityId = mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(0);
            specialityInfo.specialityName = mySqlDataReader.GetString(1);
            SpecialityIdNameMap.Add(specialityInfo.specialityId, specialityInfo.specialityName);
        }
        mySqlDataReader.Close();
        //conn.CloseConnection();
        return SpecialityIdNameMap;
    }

    //To get the list of doctors for a given speciality
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> GetDoctorSpecialityList()
    {
        conn.GetConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd1 = conn.GetCommand(Queries.GetDoctorNameForSpeciality);
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        Dictionary<string, List<string>> SpecialityDoctorMap = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
        Dictionary<Int32, string> SpecialityIdNameMap = GetSpecialityList();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Int32, string> pair in SpecialityIdNameMap)
        {
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@specialId", Convert.ToInt32(pair.Key));
            MySqlDataReader mySqlDataReader = null;
            mySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

            while (mySqlDataReader.Read())
            {
                DoctorInfo doctorInfo = new DoctorInfo();
                doctorInfo.dname = mySqlDataReader.GetString(1);
                list.Add(doctorInfo.dname);
            }
            SpecialityDoctorMap.Add(pair.Value, list);
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();
            mySqlDataReader.Close();

        }
        conn.CloseConnection();
        return SpecialityDoctorMap;
    }
```

//Model classes:-

```
public class SpecialityInfo 
{
    [Key]
    public int specialityId { get; set; }
    public string specialityName { get; set; }
}


public class DoctorInfo
{
    [Key]
    public int doctorId { get; set; }
    public string dname { get; set; }
    public int specialityId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am using asp.net mvc and c# and a razor view.

Comment: can you post your cshtml code ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question and posted the cshtml code .

Comment: what is the type of `value` ?

Comment: The value over here is list of doctor names for the specific speciality name.My implementation is wrong may be.Can you suggest me how to display the list of doctors for the particular speciality name present in the key part of the dictionary.

Comment: can you add `SpecialityDoctorMap` class as well to your post

Comment: Currently how is it displayed with this code and how do you want it to be displayed?

Comment: Did you try removing `<tr></tr>` from outside the `for each` loop.?

Comment: I am getting the entire list of doctors for every speciality in the current context.

Comment: I just want to display a particular speciality Name in a row and the corresponding doctors for that speciality in that row.

Comment: You need to do `list = new List<string>();` inside the `for each` loop in `GetDoctorSpecialityList` method.

Comment: You need to do `list = new List<string>();` inside the `for each` loop in `GetDoctorSpecialityList` method. Also remove line `cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue...` and replace it with `cmd1.Parameters["@specialId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(pair.Key);` and add line `cmd1.Parameters.Add("@specialId", SqlDbType.Integer);` before foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.That view problem has been solved.But,I have found a problem in my service class method GetDoctorSpecialityList. It is returning the set of all doctors corresponding to a particular speciality name.The GetSpecialityList is returning the proper mapped values of speciality Id and Speciality names.Can you please check the code of the method GetDoctorSpecialityList and tell the solution how to get the list of doctors for that particular specialityName.I am not able to solve this problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Please use strongly typed views instead of dynamic viewbag, it's less error prone. ViewBag is quick but not recommended way of sending data from controller to view. This way you have a model that is strongly bounded between controller and view. If the key is speciality and the List has doctor names, then in a view this would be :

Controller :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     AddService addService = new AddService();
     Dictionary<string,List<string>> SpecialityDoctorMap =
     addService.GetDoctorSpecialityList();
     return View(SpecialityDoctorMap); // passing model to view
 }
```

View :

```
    @model Dictionary<string,List<string>>

    <table>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> speciality in Model)
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@speciality.Key</td>
        @foreach(string doctorName in @speciality.Value)
        {
          <td>@doctorName</td>
        }
      </tr>                          
    }
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.But,I have not created any model for the dictionary .I have just declared the Dictionary and initialized it with the value returned  from the service class.I have uploaded the model classes and also my service class.Can You please tell me in this context.If I can do it without Creating a particular model for only the dictionary. I have model classes for the doctorInfo and specialityInfo .

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. For Dictionary you don't need special model just you need to use it in a view to be sure that data is valid. You still have Dictionary<string, List<string>> in a view but as proper key/value pair. ViewBag is dynamic and holds object type therefore is bad choice. This code does what you wanted as is without any additional class model.

Comment: Yes , I have implemented your way.Thanks a lot for this concept.But I have found a problem in my service class method GetDoctorSpecialityList. It is returning the set of all doctors corresponding to a particular speciality name.The GetSpecialityList is returning the proper mapped values of speciality Id and Speciality names.Can you please check the code of the method GetDoctorSpecialityList and tell the solution how to get the list of doctors for that particular specialityName.I have got stucked here.